# How to tag multiple friends on a post in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook, tags

I am trying to make a post of my wall and tag multiple friends on it, so far I've managed to post on my wall now only thing is left to tag. I have checked out this question in stack [Post on personal Facebook wall using ios sdk and tag multiple friends at once..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984670/post-on-personal-facebook-wall-using-ios-sdk-and-tag-multiple-friends-at-once) and also checked out the description on tagging in facebook at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/tagging/ but still not sure how should I implement this in iOS. This is my current code for posting in my wall

```
-(void)shareAdOnFacebook:(NSString *) wallMessage UserId:(NSString *) userID
{
      NSArray *permissions =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions",@"publish_stream",@"manage_friendlists", nil];

    NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Test miLineup!", @"message", @"Iphone Apps", @"name", nil];

    NSLog(@"\nparams=%@\n", params);

    NSLog(@"PERMISSIONS:%@",[[FBSession activeSession]permissions]);
    if ([[FBSession activeSession]isOpen]) {

        if ([[[FBSession activeSession]permissions]indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound) {

            [[FBSession activeSession] requestNewPublishPermissions:permissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,NSError *error){
                                                      NSLog(@"Perform operation");
                                                      [self postOnWall:wallMessage UserId:userID];
                                                  }];

        }else{
            NSLog(@"Perform operation");
            [self postOnWall:wallMessage UserId:userID];
        }
    }else{

        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"]
                                           defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceOnlyMe
                                              allowLoginUI:YES
                                         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
                                             if (!error && status == FBSessionStateOpen) {
                                                 NSLog(@"Status is Open");
                                                 [self postOnWall:wallMessage UserId:userID];
                                             }else{
                                                 NSLog(@"error");
                                             }
                                         }];
    }

}

- (void)postOnWall:(NSString *) wallMessage UserId:(NSString *) userID
{
    NSNumber *testMessageIndex=[[NSNumber alloc] init];
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"testMessageIndex"]==nil)
    {
        testMessageIndex=[NSNumber numberWithInt:100];
    }
    else
    {
        testMessageIndex=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"testMessageIndex"];
    };
    testMessageIndex=[NSNumber numberWithInt:[testMessageIndex intValue]+1];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:testMessageIndex forKey:@"testMessageIndex"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    // create the connection object
    FBRequestConnection *newConnection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];

    // create a handler block to handle the results of the request for fbid's profile
    FBRequestHandler handler =
    ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        // output the results of the request
        [self requestCompleted:connection forFbID:@"me" result:result error:error];
    };


    NSString *messageString=wallMessage;


    FBRequest *request= [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:userID parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:messageString forKey:@"message"] HTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [newConnection addRequest:request completionHandler:handler];

    // if there's an outstanding connection, just cancel
    [self.requestConnection cancel];

    // keep track of our connection, and start it
    self.requestConnection = newConnection;
    [newConnection start];
}

// FBSample logic
// Report any results.  Invoked once for each request we make.
- (void)requestCompleted:(FBRequestConnection *)connection
                 forFbID:fbID
                  result:(id)result
                   error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"request completed");

    // not the completion we were looking for...
    if (self.requestConnection &&
        connection != self.requestConnection)
    {
        NSLog(@"    not the completion we are looking for");
        return;
    }

    // clean this up, for posterity
    self.requestConnection = nil;

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"    error:%@",error);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"   ok");

    };
}
```

Through this I can post on self wall, I need to modify it to tag other users.

Answer (score 0):

See the docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed/#pubfields

You're already creating a dictionary with the "message" property, just add the "tags" and "place" property.

"tags" is a comma separated list of user ids.

Note that you can only tag people if you also specify a "place".